# What is her shoe size vs. what shoe size does she take

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say you are a shoe seller. One day, a buyer approached you and told you that she wanted to buy her daughter a new shoes.

You then asked her this:

> Shoe seller: What is her shoe size?

Or

> What shoe size does she take?

Do both of them of the **same** **meaning**? Because I think sentence1 is a bit off and unconventional...

Comment: Yes, both questions _have_ the same meaning and both would be acceptable.

Comment: Alternative seller: [*What shoe size **are you**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22what+shoe+size+are+you%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are okay; it's just a style a particular register takes.

In the UK, it's common to say:

> [*take:*](https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences-and-law/political-science-and-government/military-affairs-nonnaval/take) wear or require (a particular size of garment or type of complementary article): ***he takes size 5 boots.***

Nevertheless, I've heard this common:

> *What's her shoe size?*

Or...

> *What shoe size does she have?* (InE)

Comment: Agree, also add that "What shoe size does she **need**?" is another phrasing you might hear from a shoe seller, and that "shoe size" can be replaced with just "size" in all cases where the context is sufficiently clear.

Comment: *need* would add am ambiguity. It may be replied: she *needs* a size 9...a size bigger as she's growing.

Comment: But wouldn't that be the answer the shoe seller is looking for?

Comment: That's what I said..it'd add ambiguity. It *can be said* like that though. @the-baby-is-you

Comment: That's all I said; that you might hear it and it would be idiomatic. I'd also argue that it _removes_ ambiguity if that's actually the answer you're seeking.

Comment: To _take_ a size is perfectly acceptable in British English. See this Oxford definition:     Wear or require (a particular size of garment or type of complementary article).
"he only takes size 5 boots"

Comment: @KateBunting this is new to me! Added and edited.

Comment: In Australian English too, I’d expect either, “What’s her size?” (with shoe understood in a shoe store context.) or “What size does she take?” or even “What size is she?” (With the context again making it clear that your are not talking about body size, etc!)